# How to only show one component on click here?

Tags: angular

How can I only show one detail when I click the headline. Right now every single detail of every element will show on click.

```
<h1>Elements</h1>
<div *ngFor="let e of elements">
    <div (click)="switch = !switch">{{ element.name }}</div> <!-- Headline -->
    <app-details *ngIf="switch"></app-details> <!-- Details -->
</div>
```

Comment: `(click)="e.switch = !e.switch"` for that current element

Answer (score 0):

Every single detail of every element is showing because you are using only one variable `switch` and toggling this whenever any headline is clicked.

You have to uniquely identify the headline you are clicking, and then toggle only that element's switch.

In your component, create an array `switches` with same length as `elements` array.

```
private switches: boolean[];

// After 'elements' data is available, initialize this array.
this.switches = new Array(elements.length).fill(false);
```

Modify `*ngFor` to include an index, and pass this index to the click event handler function.

```
<h1>Elements</h1>
<div *ngFor="let e of elements; let i = index">
    <div (click)="toggle(i)">{{ element.name }}</div> <!-- Headline -->
    <app-details *ngIf="switches[i]"></app-details> <!-- Details -->
</div>
```

In the click event handler function, toggle only selected element's switch.

```
toggle(index) {     
  // Toggle selected element's detail view.
  switches[index] = !switches[index];

  // Close any other opened detail views. 
  switches.map((val, i) => i === index ? val : false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the current *index*  of the `ngFor` loop to a property, and then only *show* that *index*.

```js
<h1>Elements</h1>
<div *ngFor="let e of elements; let indx = index">
    <div (click)="show = indx">{{ element.name }}</div> <!-- Headline -->
    <app-details *ngIf="show === indx"></app-details> <!-- Details -->
</div>
```